# Not able to rotate the canvas text

Tags: qt, qml

is there any way to rotate only the text of canvas object in QML not the whole canvas object just the text i had used there by using ctx.filltext(). I want only to rotate only this text

Comment: Could you post some code describing what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ctx.save()`  and `ctx.restore()`

```
ctx.save();
ctx.rotate(90); 
ctx.fillText('etc etc', 50, 10);
ctx.restore();
```

This will allow you to only rotate that one item